# Стиль написания range-based цикла

Tags: c++, for, code-style, range

Какой стиль написания *range-based* цикла лучше использовать и почему: 1), 2), 3) или другой?

```
// 1)

// всегда
for (auto&& item : range) {

}

// 2)

// для изменяемых значений
for (auto& item : range) {

}

// для неизменяемых значений
for (const auto& item : range) {

}

// для изменяемых std::vector<bool> и т.п.
for (auto&& item : range) {

}

// 3)

// для изменяемых значений
for (auto&& item : range) {

}

// для неизменяемых значений
for (const auto& item : range) {

}
```

Связанные вопросы:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/21781857

https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130708

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994789

Comment: Зависит от того, **ЧТО ВАМ НАДО**. На чем лучше передвигаться - на велосипеде, грузовике, самолете, корабле, пешком?...

Comment: @Harry насколько я понимаю, все 3 стиля поддерживают любой use case. Если не так, исправьте

Comment: За что минус???

Comment: Нет не поддерживают, нет цикла по копиям, `for (auto item : range)`

Comment: @goldstar_labs под всеми use case имеется в виду, что используя только то, что написано в стиле, цикл будет работать для любого range и любых использований item в нём. Если в вашем стиле вы хотите использовать подобный цикл, то этот стиль подпадает под категорию "другой"

Comment: Минус поставил я, так как вопрос лишён смысла. Все приведенные конструкции легитимны в языке и лучшей среди них нет, что лучше int, short или long

Comment: @goldstar_labs я не спрашивал, какая из конструкций лучше. Я спросил, какой стиль лучше. Если бы это было неважно, то почему столько информации по этому поводу, крупные компании предоставляют свои code style guide, и почему тогда метка `code-style` существует?

Comment: Это не стиль, а  способ использования. Считаю, что вопрос нужно отредактировать, поэтому пока минус....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в чём разница между стилем и способом использования?

Comment: Лучший стиль подразумевает использовать тот или иной способ логично, в зависимости от того, что вы делаете. Это зависит от того, хотите ли вы сохранить данные в последовательности, копировать или ссылаться, безопасить  код от случайного изменения данных или нет?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так я и прошу "логично" объяснить, что из этого использовать. Одно и то же действие можно сделать разными способами в языке

Comment: смотрите первый комментарий от  Harry

Comment: @ARHovsepyan посмотрел и ответил, но он игнорирует

Comment: А почему у вас нет самого простого - `for(auto item: range)`? При небольших размерах `item` это будет выгоднее `for(const auto& item: range)`.

Comment: Стиль кода - во многом договорённости команды, о такой вкусовщине есть смысл просто договориться и следовать договорённостям.

Comment: @Harry, я вполне могу ответить на вопрос, когда удобнее передвигаться на велосипеде, когда на грузовике, а когда на самолёте. Так что было бы шикарно взять все возможные варианты и собрать из них ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну раз вы можете ответить - вам и клавиатуру в руки :) По-хорошему, тут надо начинать с того, что расписывать правила вывода типов `auto`...

Answer (score -2):

Лучше использовать первый стиль, потому что не надо думать об изменяемости значений, а всегда использовать один вариант.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/488939)

Comment: @DaemonHK дан ответ на вопрос и написано почему. Если вам не нравятся мои ответы, то это не значит что это не решения вопроса, как вы написали. Автоматически или нет неважно

Comment: @kernel этот случай не единственный, когда у вас были ответы более похожие на комментарий (у нас на so так не принято, принято набрать 50 баллов репутации на хороших ответах и комментировать в комментариях). Вам кажется, что вы дали ответ, но у нас также не принято отвечать на вопросы, на которые невозможно объективно ответить, подобного рода вопросы минусуются, закрываются.

Comment: Я видел ваши ответы, хороший технический уровень. Думаю, совершенно не составит труда набрать 50 баллов, а до этого момента стараться не отвечать на подобного рода плохо составленные вопросы.

Comment: @DaemonHK, формально, это действительно ответ на заданный вопрос. На мой взгляд, ответ неправильный, но тем не менее, это именно ответ. Думаю, стоит относиться внимательнее к проверяемым сообщениям.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109458/discussion-on-answer-by-kernel---range-based-).